Make lines of code appear 1-by-1 in a Google Colab notebook
I am teaching in Python using a Google Colab notebook. I want to make successive lines of code appear in a notebook full of code (be visible) 1-by-1 by pressing a single hotkey or crtl-key. This will help me talk through the code in real time in a video (or live) without typing and copying or cut-and-pasting.
Have not found anything simple that does what I need.
